# Wordpress not including my php file

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my code that I have calling my php file:

```
<section style="width:100%;  height:120px;  clear:both;" >
    <section class="campaign_statistics" style="background-color:#EFEFEF;">

        <?php include('progress_chart.php'); ?>

    </section>
</section>
```

However, nothing displays on the page when I call it, and when I view the page source this is what I see:

```
<section style="width:100%;  height:120px;  clear:both;" >
    <section class="campaign_statistics" style="background-color:#EFEFEF;">



    </section>
</section>
```

Everything but my php include. All of this was working fine on friday. I go and check my site this morning and it's not displaying what's in that php file. Is there a problem with wordpress? I've gone over all my code and can't find any errors and no changes were made over the weekend.

Here is a portion of the contents of my php file:

```
<?php 

if ($blog_id == 1)
    echo
    '
    <script>
    var percent = String(totalProgress.getPercent());
    document.write(totalProgress.toString());
    </script>
    '
    ;

if ($blog_id == 68)
    echo
    '
    <script>
    var percent = String(alumniProgress.getPercent());
    document.write(alumniProgress.toString());
    </script>
    '
    ;
?>
```

etc... there's about 20 of these. They're javascript calls.

Comment: What happens if you switch the `include()` to `require()`?

Comment: I everything fine with the data that progress_chart.php is pulling in? If it was working fine earlier, I wonder if the script has encountered something it can't handle, which might be preventing it from completing and outputting your chart.

Comment: Chances are you may need to do something to the affect of `<?php include('/wp-content/themes/your_theme_name/progress_chart.php'); ?>` or `<?php include '/wp-content/themes/your_theme_name/progress_chart.php' ; ?>` without the parentheses.

Comment: @andrewsi nothing, no visible change on the site at least.

Comment: @WhyAyala - in that case, there's a problem in the code in `progress_chart.php`. Can you edit your question to include its contents?

Comment: @Fred-ii- if progress_chart is in the same folder as my template that shouldn't be an issue. Right?

Comment: @WhyAyala It could. I helped someone on a different topic, yet the problem was that it needed to be the actual `path` to the folder and file and not just the file itself. Give it a try, what have you got to lose? ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- - if the file wasn't there, then changing to `require()` would have generated an error. So I'm assuming that the issue is with the contents instead

Comment: @andrewsi It could very well be the case.

Comment: @WhyAyala Can you show us what is inside `progress_chart.php` ?

Comment: Can you call progress_chart.php directly from your browser's address bar?

Comment: @WhyAyala - thank you. Where do you define `$blog_id`? Can you add `var_dump($blog_id)` inside `progress_chart.php` so we can see what its value is?

Comment: @j08691 when I call it in my browser address bar I get a blank page...

Comment: @andrewsi $blog_id is a word press variable.

Comment: $blog_id seems a var.. `the_ID();` or `get_the_ID();` are WordPress functions

Comment: Checked your error logs?

Comment: @WhyAyala - but is it being set properly? And what is it set to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of these built-in wordpress functions should work instead of a plain include:

```
get_template_part ('progress_chart');
```

or

```
include locate_template('progress_chart.php');
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template

EDIT: Use "include locate_template()" if you want progress_chart to be able to access variables from the file n which it's being included. For some reason get_template_part doesn't allow that.

Comment: Your second suggestion worked. Do you have any idea why my plain include would have just stopped working? I'm still stumped on what the cause was.

Comment: Glad it worked. I really have no idea why your includes stopped working. Something must have changed, somewhere, somehow, and that's the most I can say.